# Есть хоть какой-нибудь вменяемый SDK для PDF на C#?

Tags: c#

Решаю простую, казалось бы, задачу:
Создать приложение WinForms или WPF, где можно будет открыть PDF визуально, выделить нужные кусочки текста, и эти кусочки будут удалены (вместо них будет пустое место)

Начал с поиска вменяемого PDF viewer control.
Перебрал кучу библиотек - там быстродействие ужасное, тут тормозит, здесь криво, и т.д.
Остановился на DevExpress.
Пол-дела вроде сделано.

Причем я разобрался, как там получить список всех rectangle при выделении текста.
Но вот никаких вменяемых возможностей по редактированию текста - там нет.
В стандартном примере есть только такие вещи, как зачеркивание и выделение маркером. Штуки прикольные, но узкие. Полноценного же доступа к тексту там нет.
Ни к чему не привели ни общение с техподдержкой, ни декомпиляция кода в попытках изучить. Нужного функционала, по большому счету, просто нет...

Тогда решил применить такую схему: для самого редактирования применить библиотеку iTextSharp - а для всего остального (вплоть до получения rectangles) использовать DevExpress.
Но и библиотека iTextSharp тоже разочаровала. Это просто какая-то сборная солянка из средств для создания файлов, средств для редактирования файлов, чего-то еще, в которой даже не знаешь что гуглить.
Единственным подходящим под задачу (причем подозрительно хорошо подходящим!) было использование стандартного pdfcleanup.
Но и тут возникли проблемы. С большим трудом мне удалось сопоставить 2 разных rectangle (DevExpressовский и iTextSharpовский), результат выглядит как-то так:

```
var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
    Convert.ToSingle(inRect.Left),
    Convert.ToSingle(inRect.Top),
    Convert.ToSingle(inRect.Left) + Convert.ToSingle(inRect.Width),
    Convert.ToSingle(inRect.Top) - Convert.ToSingle(inRect.Height));
```

Но когда попробовал на реальных документах - оказалось, что портятся и окрестные буквы тоже. И сверху, и снизу, и слева, и справа. Никаких настроек ни со стороны одной либы, ни с другой я не нашел. Попытка подбора магических чисел, разумеется, не дала результата - числа, работающие при одном размере шрифта, уже не работали при другом.

Далее я рассмотрел библиотеку от RasterEdge.
Посмотрел примеры кода - по удалению все прям идеально подходило.
И более того, у либы оказывается есть еще и viewer для WPF, и для WinForms. "Как я их раньше не заметил", подумал я.
Попытался их использовать и... Просто не понял, как это делать. Нигде не описано - ни онлайн, ни в архиве, ни примеров проектов нет соответствующих. Стал добавлять ссылки (а там опять дублирование пространств имен, и непонятно какое юзать), смотреть какие есть элементы WF/WPF, какие классы - опять ничего не понял.
Лишь с трудом нашел один мануал по одному из пространств имен:

http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to-csharp/xdoc/windows-viewer/start/

Сделал все точно по нему (не считая того, что пришлось добавить кнопку и панель), запустил. Но какие PDF ни пробовал - они не открывались - вылетало.
Со второй либой таки разобрался самостоятельно. Появилось окошко с готовой кнопочкой Open, нажимаю, открываю любой PDF - опять вылет.

Таким образом, и на RasterEdgeвском визуальном viewer тоже можно ставить крест.
Теперь хочу пробовать его именно по удалению текста. Но раз он по части viewer так сильно лажает - то лучше ли будет с удалением?...

Еще есть идея попробовать оригинал iTextSharp - то есть Javaвскою библиотеку itextpdf - пусть бы хоть на ней что-то работало как следует, а там видно будет.
Ну или покопаться в сырцах iTextSharp - что займет неизвестно сколько времени...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84388/discussion-on-question-by-regkomf------sdk--pdf-).